Accessible skeleton loading (loading placeholder) HTML
In this question, we'll consider 2 examples but please note that this question is about arbitrary loading placeholder (it means that the loading placeholder could consist from any shape, not necessarily the flow of cards).
Here is the Bootstrap 5 example for the loading placeholder:
<div class="card" aria-hidden="true">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title placeholder-glow">
      <span class="placeholder col-6"></span>
    </h5>
    <p class="card-text placeholder-glow">
      <span class="placeholder col-7"></span>
      <span class="placeholder col-4"></span>
      <span class="placeholder col-4"></span>
      <span class="placeholder col-6"></span>
      <span class="placeholder col-8"></span>
    </p>
    <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-primary disabled placeholder col-6"></a>
  </div>
</div>


But is just aria-hidden="true" enough?
How the screen readers and the like will understand that the loading is in process?
Tried to add aria-label:
<div class="card" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Loading in progress. Please wait.">
 <!-- -->
</div>

For the Sep 2024, the HTML validator was complaining about this:

Possible misuse of “aria-label”.
(If you disagree with this warning, file an issue report or send e-mail to www-validator@w3.org.)

Nothing will change if to remove the aria-hidden="true".
One more example I want to consider.
<article>

  <div class="skeleton">
    <div aria-hidden="true"></div>
    <div aria-hidden="true"></div>
    <div aria-hidden="true"></div>
    <span>Loading</span>
  </div>

  <div aria-busy="true">
    <h3><a href="[…]">Glossier Roof Party</a></h3>
    <img src="[…]" […] alt="[…]">
    <p>
      Gastropub sartorial venmo hashtag […]
    </p>
  </div>

</article>

The content which is not ready to be displayed has been hidden by aria-busy="true". But, it is not hard to unmount this part from DOM during loading. If to do so, just below code will left:
<div class="skeleton">
  <div aria-hidden="true"></div>
  <div aria-hidden="true"></div>
  <div aria-hidden="true"></div>
  <span>Loading</span>
</div>

The Loading span is visually hidden, so the screen reader could know about loading. But how it will understand that the whole <div class="skeleton"> is the loading placeholder?

It’s unlikely that one card element is still in the loading state, it’s more likely that a list of cards is. Is this the case for you?

@Andy, Yes, we are considering the arbitrary loading placeholder.

"arbitrary loading placeholder" isn't a common term. what do you mean by it? how does it differ from a non-arbitrary loading placeholder?

@Sean, Sorry for the using of unclear term. I mean, the loading placeholder could be represented by any figure or combination of them, not only by card of multiple cards.

Using aria-hidden=true completely hides the content to screen readers. So it's totally useless and contradicting to put an aria-label at the same time.
Generally, this isn't a good practice to put aria-hidden=true on a big block of code:

You can easily forget to remove them all once the content is ready, especially if you put aria-hidden=true everywwhere at random like in one of your snippets
If the content has any focusable element (link, form element, etc.) inside the aria-hidden content, then you have a bigger problem: the element can be reached with tab but not with document navigation, and it might not be read when focusing it. This is one additional thing to watch out and you must not forget to remove tabindex=-1 at the same time as aria-hidden=true

Attribute aria-hidden is to be used with caution, only in well precise situations, and certainly not for a big block of code.
In fact, for your content currently in loading, it's much safer to whether:

Put the content in the DOM only when it's ready and not before
Hide the content currently in loading with CSS display:none or visibility:hidden, which guarantees to make it totally invisible, unreadable and inoperable whatever the mean used to read the page

Now for your second question about how to tell the user that something is loading, of course if you put the loading banner under aria-hidden=true, it's completely useless.
You can put such loading messages in an a live region with aria-live=polite, which makes it announced everytime the content changes.
A lot of resources provide examples of such loading banners.
Be careful: aria-live is to be used for the loading message such as "Loading, please wait", not for the content currently in loading itself.
